# Oracle Connections and VS2012

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

Got a really weird issue.

I am writing a small program that will connect to an oracle DB and pull some stats.

My issue is that I can not get my program to connect to oracle.  I am getting a "ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist" error.

My understanding is that this is a connection issue....IE It cant find the oracle DB.  But I had several of my teammates download the code and it works fine on their machines.  I can connect to the oracle DB using PL/SQL on my machine. I have checked the TNS values and they match what my teammates have.

I have been troubleshooting this for hours...anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: it means, the host you try to access doesnt exist. can you post your code you try to connect to db?

Comment: I realize that it can not connect.  The weird thing is that other people can use the same code on their laptops and it will connect.  I can also connect to the same data sources using PL/SQL - I suspect some weird setting in VS....

Comment: Turns out the issue was me.  I had my code stored on a network drive and it Visual Studio will not run it if that is the case.  Moved the code to a local drive and all worked fine.

Comment: Glad it worked! And Sorry I wasnt able to help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the issue was me. I had my code stored on a network drive and it Visual Studio will not run it if that is the case. Moved the code to a local drive and all worked fine. –  user2115732 18 secs ago   edit