# ODP.NET ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

Getting the error `ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist` when trying to call `OracleConnection` object's `Open` Method.

I am able to ping the host. The host is mentioned in tnsora as well. I am able to connect to the same host/db using Toad.

> Connections string is: Data
>   Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=XX.XX.XX.XX)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXXX)));User
>   Id=XX_XX;Password=xxxxxx;

Not sure what is the issue here. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Found Answer at [Oracle Connections and VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318602/oracle-connections-and-vs2012)

I was having my project/solution at a Network Drive. When I moved it to local drive, it worked without any issues. :)